# How do you install Aptana on Ubuntu 12.04.1?

Tags: ubuntu, aptana, ubuntu-12.04, aptana3

All,

[The instructions (only ones I could find) on how to install Aptana Studio 3 on Ubuntu 12.04 seem to fail in 12.04.1.](http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/)

That is, the installation of the dependencies work, and Aptana will run fine from the download folder...

The issues are:

1) The shortcut doesn't install properly
- Is there a 'real' installation of Aptana Studio 3 for Ubuntu, or does it have to run from a folder of files with the shortcut mentioned above?

2) When you launch the app again, no preferences or workspace options are saved...

3) generally this isn't installed with Ubuntu it seems...

Thoughts?

Thank you!!!

-m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late for this question, but for any linux newbies out there, this helped me a lot:

[Install Aptana Studio 3 on Ubuntu (text)](http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/installing-aptana-3-ubuntu)
[Install Aptana Studio 3 on Ubuntu (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5oNEhV0Dgg)

Answer (score 1):

Just found updated instructions here:

http://www.samclarke.com/2012/12/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-3-1-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/

And it seems to be working just fine!

I'll do some more tinkering...

-mb

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a guide instead of a video that you can print out and read by your self while you installing this is the links for you.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=571E71A8EF645585!358

This is a guide for the current version of ubuntu and don't cover one step to do if you got problems with the start page on ubuntu install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 with

sudo apt-get install  libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

The Guide linked here features the eclipse plugin version and covers eclipse problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

A 'real' installation in Ubuntu consists of putting the mentioned folder under /usr/local/bin and putting a .desktop file in /usr/local/share/applications (look under /usr/share/applications for examples). You can try that.

You can also search for a ppa that has an Aptana package (Google "ppa Aptana 12.04.1") or install Eclipse and look for Aptana in Eclipse's "Help->Install software" menu (maybe it's "update" instead of "install software"?).

Comment: is this a better place than putting it in the /opt/ folder?